# iOS 6 Mobile Safari slow render of large table with select elements

Tags: html, performance, ipad, ios6, mobile-safari

We're building a web application that has a page where the user sees a large table of editable items.  This table has controls on each row to move the row up/down and the option to delete the row.  Each row also has two select elements.

This table could consist of around 200 rows in extreme circumstances, it is when we have lots of rows that we run into severe performance problems.  The page is incredibly slow to scroll up and down and we see "checker-boxing" on the screen, also deleting a row takes around 30 seconds, sometimes more!  Moving up and down takes a similar amount of time, and the page is generally unusable.

We've been trying to narrow down exactly what the problem is and we're pretty sure it is to do with the select elements in the table - if we remove these from the rows; scrolling is perfect, moving up and down is ~1 second and deleting a row ~7 seconds.

If we delete a row from the bottom of the 200 row table, it is near instant.

It seems like the problem is to do with the CSS on the page, when we run the profiler it is the re-calculating of styles that is taking around 3 seconds.

The page performs fine in other browsers, any help/knowledge would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Since you are explicitly pointing out iOS 6. Is there any difference in other versions (iOS 5 and older)? If so, what differences?

Comment: the only real difference was that the scrolling seemed fine in iOS5, the other controls were still slow but still faster than iOS6, thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? We're seeing huge performance differences between large forms on our website. iOS5 was fine, but iOS6 is painfully slow.

Comment: nope:-( at the moment we're looking at rendering an alternative view for ipads... not ideal!

Answer (score 0):

We have several tables in our Web App for iOS 6, some of which contains several hundreds of rows as read-only with just text, but some contains SELECT elements as well.

Setting the table-layout to fixed had a tremendous impact on the performance. Some of the larger tables had major rendering problems with the default dynamic table width calculation, which we didnt overcome so far. This was especially the case when a row contained checkboxes.

Some tables didnt render the last line for example, or the table was cut off anywhere near the bottom, and so on.

We use a special stylesheet for the portrait mode, which changes the width of the TABLE and TD elements and which completely removes some of the columns as well.

This works really fine and had caused no side effects or problems so far.

For scrolling, we use a special DIV element surrounding the table which has a defined height and is using "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch". Even the largest table with around 850 entries scrolls without any loss of performance or flickering.

When do you render the table? During the page rendering/ ready/ load Event? 
Do you use an "innerHTML" assignment or do you create the DOM tree in the logic?

Answer (score -1):

Setting `table-layout:fixed;` as a style property on the table (in your stylesheet) might make it more respond faster. The browser has to do less calculations, downside is you have to specify column widths yourself.

Comment: i'm afraid that's not an option as we have values that change with the option selected in the select menu which changes the width of the cells, the page is also responsive so the widths need to change, thanks though - i did try it and it didn't make a difference anyway

Comment: There are ways to handle style changes on the fly (CSS classes) for data that changes. That's not reason to downvote a correct answer.